# resize a specific column in ag grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a Group by functionality enabled in my Ag Grid.

Since I might have multi level grouping (on 2 or 3 different columns) I would like to resize the Group column once user clicks on the Grouping to drill down.

I am using `onRowGroupOpened` to achieve this like so:

```
onRowGroupOpened: function(params) { ResizeGroupColumn(params); },
```

In my ResizeGroupColumn function here's what I'm doing...

```
function ResizeGroupColumn(params) {

  var groupCol = params.columnApi.GetAllColumn().map(col=>col.colDef['rowGroup'] =true);

  //however this returns all the columns. I'm only trying to return the column that has 'rowGroup' set to true. 

 //is there a better way to do this?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an assignment where you think that you are doing a comparison.
Probably a simple typo.

change

```
colDef['rowGroup'] =true
```

to

```
colDef['rowGroup'] === true
```